# Populating a ListBox from a database in C#

Tags: c#

How do I populate a ListBox with values from a database in C#?

Comment: Depends on your data binding.

Comment: It sounds like a problem on how to get data from database up to UI more than a problem with the listbox itself, I think you should read something about ADO.NET and Data Access techniques for .NET applications, after that binding data to any user control which supports data binding is usually trivial.

Comment: What database are you using?  Are you using WinForms or WPF?  Do you have any code that is accessing the database yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any ORM (such as Linq to SQL, Entity Framework or NHibernate - depending on your needs and the scale of your application) is order to read objects from the database, and then just add the properties of the objects as items to the list box.

Answer (score 0):

prepare the `List<Object>` for your database records. create the dynamic ListBox control. add control on your page by :

```
LixtBox lstBox=new ListBox();
lstBox.Datasource=//your List<object>
//Assign datamembers and value members.

Page.Controls.Add(ListBoxControl)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at ADO.NET framework but there is a lot of ways to do that...

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)